# Shared Angular component always on front

Tags: css, angular

I have an Angular component, that will be used in multiple other components. It's a sticky navbar, that stays at the top of you screen if you scroll down.
Problem is the navbar isn't on front of the things that are on the page if I scroll down.

People suggested using a high z-index in css, but since it's not feasible to define the z-index in every component the navbar is used, I'm wondering if there's a way to make this happen only in the navbar component.

Comment: Nothing holds you back from wrapping your `navbar.component.html` in a `<div>` and apply a `z-index` there.

Comment: did you put that navbar component selector on your main component?

Comment: @MuhammadDaniyal I used the navbar component as an app in an other component:

`<app-nav-bar></app-nav-bar>`

Comment: Suppose your `<app-nav-bar>` is of height `70px` then start your next components position like this: `top:70px`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, my problem was, that I forgot to set a background color for my component. Thanks anyways.

Answer (score -1):

Here's a [working example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-eh8zbm) of what you're requesting. You have to make the navbar *ideally* a new component, and have that component stick on top. I think the example is pretty clear and minimal.

Good luck!

Comment: That's pretty much what I've done, but the content won't be necessarily a component/app in itself.

Comment: I have updated the example with an architectural design pattern that allows you to have app navigation, to navigate modules, and even subnavigation to navigate components of each modules.